# How to perform proxy authentication in ChromeDriver using Selenium + Java?

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Alright, so my problem is that I can't find a way to launch Chrome with authenticated proxy connection. 
What I have is: proxy ip, port, username and password.
What I need: to launch Chrome instance with connection with this proxy using Selenium

what I've tried:

```
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--proxy-server=USERNAME:PASS@IP_ADDRESS:PORT"));
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

and:

```
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
    proxy.setHttpProxy("IP_ADDRESS:PORT");
    proxy.setSocksUsername("USERNAME");
    proxy.setSocksPassword("PASSWORD");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setProxy(proxy);
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Unfortunately, none of this approaches work...

Comment: what error you see ?

Comment: @AmitJain the browser starts up normally, however the IP is still mine (no proxy routing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by setting system-level proxy:

```
    System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");

    // http
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "1.2.3.4");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", 8080);
    System.setProperty("http.proxyUser", "username");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword", "pass");

    // https
    System.setProperty("https.proxyHost","1.2.3.4");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", 8080);
    System.setProperty("https.proxyUser", "username");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyPassword", "pass");

    System.setProperty("jdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes", "");
    System.setProperty("jdk.https.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes", "");

    Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("user", "pass".toCharArray());
        }
    });
```